# Read memory from application which does not allow it

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dump, openprocess

I am currently trying to read the entirety of the memory of a game which blocks calls to `OpenProcess` and `ReadProcessMemory` (I believe this is done through a windows driver/service, although I'm not sure how).

I use the following code to do try and open the process and read its memory to a file:

```
HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid);
if (!process) {
    cout << "Failed to open process.";
    return 1;
}
cout << "Successfully opened processs." << endl << "Dumping memory to mem.dmp..." << endl;

ofstream fout;
fout.open("mem.dmp");

char *base = (char *)0;
char *readCount = (char *)0;
do {
    char buffer[PAGE_SIZE];

    if (ReadProcessMemory(process, base, buffer, PAGE_SIZE, NULL) != 0)
    {
        fout << buffer;
    }

    base += PAGE_SIZE;
    readCount++;
} while (base != 0);
if (readCount == 0) {
    cout << "Warning: No memory was read from the process." << endl;
}
fout.flush();
fout.close();
```

However, when run, this cannot even open the process.

The only way to get past the driver blocking the process from being opened for memory reading is to dump the entirety of the physical memory to a file. I have no idea how to do this, other than having to set windows to dump all of the physical memory on a blue screen, and then forcing my computer to shutdown with a blue screen. This is obviously quite inconvenient as I will want to analyse the application's memory quite frequently.

Is there any way to dump all of the physical memory without using this method on Windows? I know virtually nothing about the driver or how it works so it would be almost impossible to work out another way of bypassing it.

Comment: Dumping physical memory won't do it, because of virtual memory.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a way of bypassing this block? Isn't the whole point of it to prevent what you're trying to do?

Comment: The first thing to try is enabling debug privilege before the call to OpenProcess, this will bypass the process DACL.  Failing that, your best bet is probably the [kernel-mode debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553382(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply - can't all virtual memory be accessed from the pagefile? There are some tools which can do this. And yes, the whole point of the block is to prevent what I'm doing, but I would like to do some analysis and I can't at the moment.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for the reply. I will look into your suggestions.

Comment: The best solution is to learn more about Windows. Also, there are web sites dedicated to this type of thing; about games and how to analyze them. Also look for reverse-engineering techniques. Also look for motherboard diagnostic boards; put one of them in your system and then you can get at memory anywhere and no software can defeat that. You should go to gaming sites and things like that.

Comment: @rodit I don't know Window's architecture very well, I don't know what the pagefile is. But if you can access all processes' memory from it, then it's not the same thing as physical memory. Physical memory just contains those portions of virtual memory that happen to be loaded into RAM at the moment.

Comment: Start the process with your program in suspended state. Overwrite the "IsBeginDebugged" flag in the TEB/PEB. Resume the process. Before reading, set the VirtualQueryEx permissions to make sure you can read. Then read. Restore the VirtualQueryEx flags back to normal when you are finished reading. Use `NtOpenProcess or ZwOpenProcess` to open the process just in case the process is hooking `OpenProcess` or something.

Comment: @user34660 thanks for the reply. I am currently using a laptop so hardware solutions will be quite difficult for me to implement. The software is heavily protected (pretty sure it's protected by something like SecuROM or VMProtect).

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the reply - I doubt I'll be able to do that very successfully but I'll give it some research and I'll try it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the clarification - I'm pretty sure the pagefile on Windows is for virtual memory (well Wikipedia points me in that direction, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the "0th" memory position, that is not possible (SO does not allow you to do it):

```
char *base = (char *) 0;
```

You should set correcly the address where you wanna read, and that address must be a readable address. Check the ReadProcessMemory doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **lpBaseAddress [in]**:  A pointer to the base address in the specified
>   process from which to read. Before any data transfer occurs, the
>   system verifies that all data in the base address and memory of the
>   specified size is accessible for read access, and if it is not
>   accessible the function fails.

Check also the examples in this post
[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/166135/)